# Why use ServletRequestAware instead of ServletActionContext?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, struts2, actioncontext

To get a servlet request in Struts 2 we can use either `ServletRequestAware`   or `ServletActionContext`. However, in a particular internet [resource](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-get-the-httpservletrequest-in-struts-2/), it is told that `ServletRequestAware`  should be used instead of `ServletActionContext`.

Does that have something to do with the fact that `ServletActionContext`  will be a shared resource in a multi-threaded environment or is there any other reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ServletActionContext`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.html) is a helper class that contains only static methods, one of them used to retrieve servlet request from action context.
But action context is [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html), so it can't be shared in multi-threaded environment.

There's also no multi-threded environment per request in Struts2, except a background thread used by the [`execAndWait` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html).

The reason to use `ServletRequestAware` is because it's guaranteed method to obtain a servlet request object if `servletConfig` interceptor is included in the stack.

You can use `ServletActionContext`  from anywhere, but it doesn't guarantee that a request object instead of `null` will be returned.

Answer (score 6):

`ServletRequestAware` is a better approach because it decouples action methods from static accessors.

In order to test something using `ServletActionContext` you need to mock static methods *and* mock the request. To test `ServletRequestAware` methods you only need to mock the request.

While tools exist that make mocking static methods easier, it's easier yet to implement the interface and pass in a mocked request. This is *the* reason `ServletRequestAware` exists.